# PHP using for inside for

Tags: php, loops, random

can someone help me to code executing data using random or sequential api list

i have 10 data and 3 api list, and i want the code doing like this :

```
data 1  executed by api 1
data 2  executed by api 2
data 3  executed by api 3
data 4  executed by api 1
data 5  executed by api 2
data 6  executed by api 3
data 7  executed by api 1
data 8  executed by api 2
data 9  executed by api 3
data 10 executed by api 1
```

i try to code like this and the result was not as i expected :

```
if(isset($argv[1])){
$no = 1;
$api = 0;
$total = count(explode("\n",file_get_contents($argv[1])));
$listapi = file_get_contents($argv[2]);
$listml = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
$ex = explode("\n",$listapi);
$exx = explode("\n",$listml);
for ($ee = 0; $ee < count($exx); $ee++) {
    for ($api = -1; $api < count($listapi); $api++) {
    $send = json_decode($curl->get($ex[$api]."?ee=".$exx[$ee]));
    $no++;
    echo "OK\n";
    if ($api % count($ex) == 3) {
        $api = -1;
        echo "Rolling\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through `data` array find relevant item in `api` array in loop as shown in bottom.

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$item){
    echo "data $item executed by api ".$api[$key%count($api)]."\n";
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/no6YR)

Comment: but how if the api and the data is using count not range?

Comment: @SmithGeorge What do you mean by *data is using count*? Maybe https://3v4l.org/2OpXk

Comment: i mean is like $data = count("datalist.txt");

Comment: @SmithGeorge The `count()` return integer not array.